# Unable to get value while running php page on terminal

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs

I have simple websocket and have file server.php which is suppose to run as

```
php server.php
```

In server.php I have following code one of the functions of websocket. I stored information in ngStorage with help of angularjs. I successfully stored data in ngStorage. When I pull value with ajax in browser I can get value stored in ngStorage. When I run the page on terminal like **php server.php** I get plain text without value. It just shows exactly as below.

```
function wsOnOpen($clientID) {

    echo '<div ng-app="example">
        <div ng-controller="ExampleController">  
                  //loading value stored in ngStorage
                  <input type="hidden" ng-init="loadData()"/> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="orange"></div>';//displaying value here with ajax
```

So in terminal I want to see value not these following code I wrote. I am new to such technology, I would appreciate your patience.

Comment: Javascript only runs in a browser not in a terminal. You can simulate a browser in your terminal with PhantomJS.